# Reading lines of a float and converting to integers

Tags: c, scanf, floating-point-conversion

Write a C program that reads lines containing floating point values of type double one per line from the standard input ( e.g. using scanf ), converts those values to integers and then prints those values as right justified integers in a 20-character wide field one per line on the standard output.

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

My biggest problem is I don't know where to start. Any tips and help would be appreciated.

Comment: `int main() {/* read a number using scanf() */ /* convert the namber to int */ /* print the number with %20d */return 0;}`

Comment: Thank You I was just trying to figure out the best way to get started.

Comment: Since this sounds like it's for school, you should start with what you've learned so far that's relevant.

Comment: I'm just starting a class its seeing what we know about C which they changed curriculums on us so I didn't learn this while other people have.

Answer (score 1):

**The concept is to TYPECAST the float to an integer.**

The loop here is for multiple values if you want.

This is the program. I hope this helps; it runs as you want.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    float n;
    int t;
    //loop here
        scanf("%f", &n);
        t = (int)n;
        printf("%20d", t);
    // end loop here
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This was a neat outline before I tampered with it, but note that (a) the question asked about `double` rather than `float`, (b) the value returned by `scanf()` should be checked to ensure that a value was read (and in a loop, the test should be the loop condition), and (c) the output should end with a newline.  The changes necessary are simple, though (as in, fewer than 20 non-white space characters need adding).